# What data type to use for drop downlist and radio button in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, enums

I'm using java bean, servlet JSP and mysql for my project. I need to know what data type to use for drop down list and radio button in mysql.

For radio button I only have 2 options so I planned to use boolean. For Drop down list I tried using enum (I initialised in mysql database and it says some error). I used enum because i did some research and a lot resources said use enum.[image]
I've attached the picture that shows error message.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late. But anyway, here goes. 
Go back and select the ENUM datatype again and in the brackets single quote each option and separate each 'single quoted' option with a comma and a single space after the comma. e.g.
ENUM('Blue', 'Black', 'Red', 'Green')

or

```
ENUM('20', '21', '22', '23')
```

It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate table for the dropdown list with id and the visible value. The ID can be numeric (tinyint/int).